# using sharepoint OOTB DragDrop.js library in Custom webpart

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, csom

I implemented drag and drop file upload functionality using REST api in my webpart .
But i found an OOTB sharepoint dragdrop.js library which has numerous methods to create drag drop control. 
 Does anyone has an example to create a dragdrop control using this OOTB dragdrop.js?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please check this example on DragDrop functionality: https://medium.com/quick-code/simple-javascript-drag-drop-d044d8c5bed5